# How to set Nodata values from -9999 to value=1 in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, nodata

I am trying to export a text file with the tool Raster to ASCII. But in text file the NoData values = -9999. How can I change the Nodata values from -9999 to 1?

The text file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you would need to first change the NoData value to 1 in ArcGIS Pro using Raster Calculator.

In the Calculator use the below expression:

```
Con(IsNull(*inputraster*),1,*inputraster*)
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Con Geoprocessing tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) in ArcGIS Pro.

- [Help Doc](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/con-.htm)

Comment: thank you for your answer and time